# Pull `t` out of trig functions and solve it

Tags: trigonometry, nonlinear-system, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to come up with an analytical solution for inverse kinematics for my robot; but some of my trig has left my brain!

The robot is very simple; with one rotary and one prismatic joint. I'm looking to calculate the rotation; which is `t`.

I've got the below equation which gives me the `z` co-ord from `t` and `e & w` which are constants that I need to tune the robot.

```
z = e*sin(t) + cos(t)/sin(t)*(-x - e*cos(t)) + w
```

So basically; I just need to solve the above for `t`.

I did the below attempt at simplification; and then I get stuck.

```
z = e*sin(t) + cos(t)/sin(t)*(-x - e*cos(t)) + w
z = e*sin(t) - x*cos(t)/sin(t) -e*cos^2(t)/sin(t) + w
z - w = (e*sin^2(t) - x*cos(t) - e*cos^2(t) ) /sin(t)
z - w = (e*(1 - cos^2(t)) - x*cos(t) - e*cos^2(t) ) /sin(t)
z - w = (e - e*cos^2(t)) - x*cos(t) - e*cos^2(t) ) /sin(t)
z - w = (e - 2e*cos^2(t)) - x*cos(t) ) /sin(t)
```

Is this going down the correct path to solve?
How do I go from here toward getting to the form `t = ...`

Thanks

Comment: In your equation for $z$, should the equation read $z = e \sin t + \dfrac {\cos t}{-x  - e \cos t} + w$?  (You should use MathJax to typeset your equation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact solution involves solving a degree 4 polynomial equation.

Let $t=2s$ and convert all trig functions to $\tan(s)$

$$
z={\frac {3 e\tan \left( s \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( s \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}-{\frac {x}{2\tan \left( s \right) }}+\frac{\tan
 \left( s \right) x}{2}-{\frac {e}{2\tan \left( s \right)  \left( 1+
 \left( \tan \left( s \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }}-{\frac {e
 \left( \tan \left( s \right)  \right) ^{3}}{2+2\, \left( \tan \left( 
s \right)  \right) ^{2}}}+w
$$
Let $T = \tan(s)$, we have to solve a quartic equation
$$
 \left( -e+x \right) {T}^{4}+ \left( 2\,w-2\,z \right) {T}^{3}+6\,e{T}
^{2}+ \left( 2\,w-2\,z \right) T-e-x = 0
$$
Once we solve that for $T$, our answer is $t = 2\arctan T$.

---

An example to illustrate the "let $t=2s$" part.  Suppose we want to solve
$\sin t = (\cos t)+1$ for $t$.  Let $t=2s$,
$$
\sin(2s)=\cos(2s)+1 .
$$
Convert everything to $\tan$
$$
\frac{2\tan s}{1+\tan^2 s} = \frac{1 - \tan^2 s}{1+\tan^2 s}+1
\\
\frac{2\tan s}{1+\tan^2 s} = \frac{2}{1+\tan^2 s}
$$
so we get
$$
2\tan s = 2
$$
Write $T = \tan s$, our equation is
$2T=2$.  This has solution $T=1$.  Then $\tan s = 1$ so $s \arctan 1 = \pi/4$.  Finally, $t=2s = 2(\pi/4) = \pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; unfort my maths skills are struggling to follow along. I think I'm not following $t=2s$ - since $t$ is defined in the original equation; how can it be redefined here? And then at the end; doesn't $t = 2\arctan T$ expand to $t = 2\arctan (\tan(t/2))$, which has $t$ on the left and the right side.

Comment: You write $t=2s$.  You solve for $s$.  You multiply the answer by $2$ to get $t$.

Comment: Thanks again for the guidance. The refactoring and simplification in the first two steps t=2s and convert all trig functions to tan(s) & $T = \tan(s)$ seem quite involved; do you usually use software to help with them; or after enough practice do they just flow out naturally? And I guess I've spend too much time reading program source code; so my brain reads "variable on the left is being set equal to variable on the right" whereas I should read it more as the "is equal to" programming construct. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction there too.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=2 \tan^{-1}(y)$, simplify and expand to get
$$-(e+x)+ 2( w- z)y+6 e y^2+ 2( w- z)y^3+ (x-e)y^4=0$$ which is a quartic and could be solved with radicals (don't try - it would lead to monsters !).

If you are able to provide bounds for $t$, it could be possible to do a few things (I hope !).

For example, if $y$ is supposed to be small, consider the equation as the start of a Taylor series and use series reversion to get
$$y=Z+\frac{3 e }{z-w}Z^2+ \left(\frac{18 e^2}{(w-z)^2}-1\right)Z^3+O\left(Z^4\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad Z=\frac{e+x}{2( w- z)}$$

**Edit**

If $t$ is small, we could build the $[1,3]$ Padé approximant and get the *estimate*
$$t=\frac{(e+x) \left((e+x) (11 e+2 x)+6 (w-z)^2\right)}{2 (w-z) \left((e+x) (11 e+2x)+3 (w-z)^2\right)}$$

Comment: @brent You can see the exact solutions to $y$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-e%2Bx%29%2B2%28w-z%29y%2B6ey%5E2%2B2%28w-z%29y%5E3%2B%28x-e%29y%5E4+solve+for+y). I doubt it's very useful, though.

Comment: Thanks for the input aswell. As I noted in my other comments; I seem to have jumped quite far beyond my can-do math limit. As far as I think I can follow; this answer is in line with the other one; just with slightly different substitutions?